# 'Documents.Open' vs. 'Documents.Add' using Word VBA

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba

I am launching a Word document using VBA in Access which will import content from the form being filled into a template document.

I have tried to use both `Documents.Open` and `Documents.Add`, both of which work, but I'm not sure which one I *should* be using.

(I have previously had some intermittent issues using Documents.Open, but I do wonder if that was to do with some other errors in the code.)

Can anyone advise the best way to action this in VBA?

Comment: `Open` *opens* an existing doc, `Add` *creates* a new one. Make up your mind what you need.

Comment: Can you please supply the code that's causing you issues? We can't help you with something that we can't see; see how to create a [mcve] and also take a look at [ask].

Comment: At minimum you should state exactly what you want to do. Discussing `Documents.Open` and `Documents.Add` for a particular problem should be OK. But it is more difficult to discuss without context. Without context @FunThomas gave you your options.

Comment: In response to the comments here and the close vote reason: This *is* a clear problem statement: "...[data] being filled into a template document" when the question is: "should I use `Documents.Open` or `Documents.Add`?" No additional code is necessary; this is **not a deugging** question - it's a question about how to correctly use Word's object model and is thus on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to create new documents from a template (whether a doc, docx, docm, dot, dotx or dotm file), which appears to be the case, then `Documents.Add` is what you should be using.

Usually in such a scenario the original document (the template) should not be changed - `Documents.Add` ensures this. Workarounds for using `Documents.Open`, such as saving under a different file name, are an additional step (inefficient) and can go wrong.

An additional factor, when the template is a true template (dot, dotx, dotm) is that any new document by default retains a link to the template (is "attached" to the template). This means the document can share building blocks, Ribbon UI, keyboard shortcuts and (assumging not docx) macro code stored in the template.

On the other hand, if a new document should *contain* (inherit) content from the "template" such as macros, Ribbon UI or keyboard shortcuts present in the "template" `Documents.Add` would need to be used with document (doc, docx, docm) file as template.

Comment: Thank you for your clear and concise explanation. It would appear that Add is what I should be using as the VBA loads a Docx which contains fields which are then filled. One issue I do have is that when I change the VBA to Add, each time Word launches, it defaults to the 'Web View' mode. Any advice on how to avoid this as reverting back to Open fixes this issue.